# Using unquoted strings in with `dplyr` verbs: `select` and `arrange` working differently

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyeval

I am trying to unquote a string for use in `dplyr::arrange`. It does not appear to work. However, it appears to work correctly in `dplyr::select`.
Am I missing something or doing something wrong here?

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(x = c(1, 2, 3),
             y = c(8, 6, 3))

v <- 'y'

# `select` works with `!!v` 

df %>% select(y)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 1
#>       y
#>   <dbl>
#> 1     8
#> 2     6
#> 3     3

df %>% select(!!v)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 1
#>       y
#>   <dbl>
#> 1     8
#> 2     6
#> 3     3

# `arrange` not work with `!!v`

df %>% arrange(y)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>       x     y
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     3     3
#> 2     2     6
#> 3     1     8

df %>% arrange(!!v)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>       x     y
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     8
#> 2     2     6
#> 3     3     3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert your string to variable first (using `sym()`) then unquote it inside `arrange()`.

```r
df %>% arrange(!!sym(v))

#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>       x     y
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     3     3
#> 2     2     6
#> 3     1     8
```

`select()` can directly take string input but it's not recommended

```r
df %>% select(v)

#> Note: Using an external vector in selections is ambiguous.
#> i Use `all_of(v)` instead of `v` to silence this message.
#> i See <https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/faq-external-vector.html>.
#> This message is displayed once per session.
#> # A tibble: 3 x 1
#>       y
#>   <dbl>
#> 1     8
#> 2     6
#> 3     3
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: It is generally better to use `.data` than `sym()`. The latter will work well most of the time but might have issues in rare corner cases. In general, if you don't have a good grasp of NSE, it's better to stick with `{{` and `.data`.

Comment: Regarding passing a string to `select()`, just wrap it in `all_of()`, as recommended in that warning message.

Comment: Thanks @LionelHenry!

Answer (score 2):

In selecting verbs, use `all_of()` or `any_of()`. the former causes an error if not all variables are present in the data frame, the latter is lenient (and in general more useful for deselecting)

```r
df %>% select(all_of(v))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 1
#>       y
#>   <dbl>
#> 1     8
#> 2     6
#> 3     3
```

In action verbs, like `arrange()` or `mutate()`, select single variables by subsetting the `.data` pronoun:

```r
df %>% arrange(.data[[v]])
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>       x     y
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     3     3
#> 2     2     6
#> 3     1     8
```

You can also use selections in action verbs by using `across()`:

```r
df %>% arrange(across(starts_with("y")))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>       x     y
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     3     3
#> 2     2     6
#> 3     1     8
```

Which means you can use `all_of()` as well to select from a character vector:

```r
df %>% arrange(across(all_of(v)))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>       x     y
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     3     3
#> 2     2     6
#> 3     1     8
```